# How can I mirror vertex groups after painting? No solution is working

Tags: rigging

I am trying to rig a model, using Blender 3.5.0, and for some reason I had it in my mind that when you do a .l and .r naming scheme for bones and vertex groups that weight paint would copy automatically, but that clearly isn't the case. Now I'm trying to mirror the weights but I'm having no luck.
I tried the "copy vertex group, mirror it, and rename it" trick, but that would mirror both the copy and the original, even if I pressed the lock button on the original, even if I renamed it before mirroring it.
I tried checking the "Mirror vertex groups" box, but when I painted with it on, it did nothing to the opposite side vertex group.
The only modifiers I have on it is the armature modifier...
What am I doing wrong?

I am going to try and link the file just in case. The weighting is only half done, the vertex groups I was fighting with were the shrug.L and .R. I'm not worried about the weighting errors, I can fix that, I'm just worried about the mirroring.

[LittleFellowTroubleshooting.blend](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1frqPSMXlOf_AozNJGik2BT_cwpWJLeUR)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the *Mirror* modifier, parent the object to the armature, weight paint, then apply the *Mirror* modifier, the opposite vertex groups will be automatically created.

If you don't have the *Mirror* modifier anymore, I don't know if you can automatically duplicate and mirror several or all the vertex groups that have a _R or _L suffixe (that would be useful), but in order to mirror the groups one by one you can:

Apply the rotation in *Object* mode (maybe it's your problem here), paint the weight for the vertex group called *hand_L* for example, duplicate it with *Copy Vertex Group*, select the new group, *Mirror Vertex Group*, rename the group *hand_R*.

Comment: You were right, the mirror modifier did the trick. I deleted half of the verticies, added it back, and it worked like a charm. thanks!

Comment: Yes but i think that the answer to your precise question is that you didn't apply the rotation?